# My =HYPERLINK links to Google sheets cells do not work

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink

This is a failed hyperlink.

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",indirect(CTRL_LinkToPlanner)),"Plnr")
```

The value at the indirect location is A62.

Clicking the link provides the address to go to manually (#$A$62) but the link does nothing.

Copying the link gives

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZDXvCtpVMrSWiWAqD2xls2WczhX6kMJvOHeFYW9zy8/edit#$A$62
```

I also tried this URL version -

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&"1FZDXvCtpVMrSWiWAqD2xls2WczhX6kMJvOHeFYW9zy8"&"/edit#gid=0&range="&CTRL_LinkToPlanner,"Plnr")
```

It failed too, although similar code with a different sheet

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&"1bnIRtuOOCSw82zFSgIUUqdhYKnNIBvymkcvYuZ0I5Eg"&"/edit#gid=0&range="&"d5","Plnr")
```

works.
I verified both spreadsheet IDs.

I'm not expert in this area. Here is how I tried to figure it out..

Copilot gave me this -
The Target Cell is Empty or Hidden: Make sure that the target cell (A10) is not empty or hidden. If it is empty, the link will not work. If it is hidden, you may need to unhide it first.
The Link Text is Not Visible: Make sure that the link text (“plnr”) is visible in the cell. If it is not visible, you may need to adjust the cell width or height to display it.
The Link is Not Clickable: Make sure that the link is clickable by selecting the cell and pressing Ctrl + K on Windows, Command (⌘) + K on Mac, or Ctrl + Alt + K on ChromeOS. This will open the Insert link dialog box, where you can verify the link URL and text.
The Link is Broken or Invalid: Make sure that the link URL is correct and valid. If it is broken or invalid, you may need to edit or remove the link and create a new one.

I tried those things with no luck.

Then it told me to clear cache and cookies and restart the browser. I did that. Same behavior.
Then it said to try a different browser. I was using Firefox. Tried Edge. Same behavior.

I diddled with the syntax, building it out a piece at a time. Each piece worked, but no luck at the end..

I went to an empty sheet and just played with links. The links to external sites work, and the URL version of the problem code also worked there, but not the simpler "#" version. I was able to use the empty sheet version to launch that sheet from my original sheet, but replacing the url with the one for my original sheet created a syntax error - the only change was the URL, which I copied from the browser and verified.

I added the sheet name to the linked address. No difference.

Comment: What do you mean when you say this one failed? `=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&"1FZDXvCtpVMrSWiWAqD2xls2WczhX6kMJvOHeFYW9zy8"&"/edit#gid=0&range="&CTRL_LinkToPlanner,"Plnr")`. I have just tried it (reproducing the named range and with different sheet ID) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CTRL_LinkToPlanner has "$" symbols in it, you can try deleting them:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&"1FZDXvCtpVMrSWiWAqD2xls2WczhX6kMJvOHeFYW9zy8"&"/edit#gid=0&range="&SUBSTITUTE(CTRL_LinkToPlanner,"$",""),"Plnr")
```

---

UPDATE with Google Apps Script:

You can try with this script that takes the parameter like `#TLSdata!A81` (with or without "#") and converts it to a string like the link `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Bds9jvB952lfKQwiQ8NGSmNBlCOgSb8Fc-sFg4YxN8/edit#gid=1530352697&range=a81`

```
function getInfo(cellValue) {
  var matches = cellValue.match(/(?:#)?([^!]+)!(.+)/);

  if (matches && matches.length === 3) {
    var sheetName = matches[1];
    var range = matches[2];

    // Get the spreadsheet by name
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // Check if the sheet exists
    if (sheet) {
      // Get the GID of the sheet
      var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
      var id = spreadsheet.getId();
      // Return the result
      var result = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + id + '/edit#gid=' + gid + '&range=' + range;
      Logger.log(result);
      return result;
    } else {
      // If the sheet doesn't exist, return an error message
      Logger.log("Sheet '" + sheetName + "' not found");
      return "Sheet '" + sheetName + "' not found";
    }
  } else {
    // If the formula format is not as expected, return an error message
    Logger.log("Invalid formula format");
    return "Invalid formula format";
  }
}
```

[image]

You can use it like =GETINFO(A1), and also grab it with HYPERLINK:

```
=HYPERLINK(GETINFO(A1),"Text of the Hyperlink")
```

[image]

Comment: Cleanup up and re-posted –
  
Response to dataful.tech – 
It just did nothing. 

Response to Martin – 
The $ symbols are added by the software. I have taken them out with this change –
"=hyperlink("#"&SUBSTITUTE("TLSdata!"&CELL("address",INDIRECT(CTRL_LinkToPlanner)),"$",""),"Plnr")". 
It now resolves to  = hyperlink("#TLSdata!A81",”Plnr”) – no $. But still a dead link.

Comment: General information regarding the HYPERLINK formula approach.
1. The indirect location contains "'TLSdata'!A81". 
2. If I manually remove the # (no more HYPERLINK) the link works, but I lose the ability to get the address indirectly. I need that because the address is dynamic.
a. With the link working, if I manually remove the sheet name (TLSdata) it shows no error but quits working. So the sheet name seems to be required.
3. Removing the # from the HYPERLINK formula creates an invalid link.

Comment: 4. If I remove the $’s and indirection (=HYPERLINK("#A81","Plnr") it shows no error but the link is dead.

Comment: 5. I was thinking that maybe the problem is something different. I don't know this, but the evidence seems to indicate that the "#" hyperlinks are treated as browser hyperlinks with the “Range=” qualifier, meaning they reload the page and put the cursor at the linked cell. This TLSdata sheet is not the sheet that loads first in this workbook. I branch to it later in Apps Script. So ... maybe it does not know what to do when gid=0 and the link is not to the first-loaded sheet. Possible?

Comment: a. That was a red herring. I swapped the locations of the tabs and it changed nothing. 
b. I also tried “gid=1” to match the sheet location. No luck.

Comment: General information regarding the URL approach. I gave up on the formula and worked on the URL. 
1. Using a URL launches the sheet and goes to the right tab. However, it does not go to cell A81. 
2.  Just for grins I created a similar link to a simpler table.  
docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Bds9jvB952lfKQwiQ8NGSmNBlCOgSb8Fc-sFg4YxN8/edit#gid=0&range=a15
a. That worked, including going to the right row.

Comment: 3. I can use a script to populate the link as follows to allow a dynamic link
- The script is below–
LOClinkString = GBLsheetTLSdataID + "/edit#gid=1&range=" + LOClinkToPlanner
LOCrichText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
 .setText("Plnr")
 .setLinkUrl(LOClinkString)
.build();
   GBLsheetTLSdata.getRange("TLS_LinkToPlanner")
.setRichTextValue(LOCrichText);

4. The script, even if wrong at this point, is not the problem. I tested the URL’s with manual cut and paste.

Comment: 5. I think my startup scripts are perhaps confusing it, as mentioned above. 
6. My simple testing that was successful on the simpler file just launched a new copy. However, I think yesterday’s URL testing showed that if you launch the file you are in it does not create a new copy. Please confirm. If it launches a new copy it is of no value to me here.

Comment: General information regarding both approaches.
1. Somewhere in the midst of all this experimentation I lost the ability to manually edit the link. I think it was with the URL version only, but did not verify.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies. Despite my attempt to clean it up, that's still a lot to read and not easy to follow. If you are expert in this area my core problem is that I am unable to create a dynamic link to another cell in a google sheet that runs a startup script that puts it on another sheet. The above ramblings describe my failed efforts to do it with the HYPERLINK command and with a URL. Thanks for any help., –

Comment: @user23341160 - See the update of my post

Comment: Many thanks Martin. That fixed it. That approach is elegant and I'm sure I will use that code somewhere, but your formula and the sources for ID and GID are what I used here. I ended up with this, based on your code. I stuck the required strings and links in LOCxxx variables earlier.
 
- LOCformula = 'hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' +              LOC_TLSdataSheetID + '/edit#gid=' +  LOC_TLSdataTabID + '&range=' + LOClinkToPlanner + '","Plnr")' - 

- GBLsheetTLSdata.getRange("TLS_LinkToPlanning")
      .setFormula(LOCformula) -

Comment: I still don't how why this
- var LOCformula = 'hyperlink("#"& CTRL_LinkToPlanner,"Plnr")' - 
fails. It builds a link that look like the other one but it is dead. But with the new stuff working I am not going to chase that. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it's working! Consider marking the question as answered 